# How to automatically keep the smart indent in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I don't quite know how to phrase this question, but basically what happens is:

if i smart indent in visual studio, then click somewhere else on the page or even on the exact same line that has the smart indent, it then goes away, as if I'd had no indenting at all, not even block indenting.

It just puts the cursor/insertion point at the very beginning of the line.

**EDIT:** BTW I recently formatted my computer and I'm almost certain this wasn't the case before, I'm guessing it's a setting, but I've been fiddling around with all the settings trying to change this, but I can't.

Comment: Frustrating... what is your question? (Hint - it usually has a `?` appended...)

Comment: How do I stop the smart indent from disappearing when I click somewhere?

Comment: @tim.stasse: Do you have any plugins installed that might be altering the format of the code?

Comment: I'm using nFringe to write unrealscript, can a plugin really change the behavior of smart tabs?

Answer (score 0):

Open Tools->Options. Navigate to Text Editor on the LHS. Select the source type (C++, VB, etc.). Open the tree view node and select Tabs. There, on the RHS you'll find your option

Comment: Thank you anyway, I know about those settings already but that's not my problem